# Sending additional request parameter with Jquery Upload

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I'm trying to send to Spring Controller additional request parameter through Jquery Upload plugin. I have code as below:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        formData: {
              'projectName': $('#projectSelect :selected').val()
        },
        done : function(e, data) {
            console.info (data);
            //some more logic
        }
 });
```

What I'm trying to do is to sent the project name to which file corresponds. I tried this formData and used controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<KnownIssueUiModel> upload(@RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("projectName") String projectName) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("PROJECT NAME: " + projectName);
    // some logic
    return issues;
}
```

But when I use code as this I get "400 (Required String parameter 'projectName' is not present)". When I tried to use RequestBody and ProjectDto class with getter and setter for projectName and default constructor I got 415 (unsupported media type). I would really appreciate if someone could advice me how can Isend to Spring this project name with file upload.

Comment: Are you executing the above code before or after the user selects something from the dropdown?

Comment: There is always a default value in dropdown, so user has always something selected.

Comment: I don't know Spring, I thought maybe it treated an empty value as not present, and assumed that the default value of the dropdown was an empty string.